# VBA Word Macro to insert a line break in the last line if there is a word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some documents in which I need to change the content of the last line of the page to the next page if there is a word in it. I'm trying to establish the first word of the last line of each page as a Range so that I can establish an IF...Then... Rule, do you know how to do that? I also tried to create a Macro where I go to a certain page, then I move "x" number of lines (until the last line) and copy the content of that line so that I can replace it inserting a line break, but the problem with this is that y can replace what is copied in the "Replacement cell", but not in the "Finding Cell", Do you have any suggestions?

See

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Name:="2"
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=52, Name:=""
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text Dialog _
        "***Word1   word2***"
    .Replacement.Text Dialog "^p^c"
    .Forward Dialog True
    .Wrap Dialog wdFindAsk
    .Format Dialog False
    .MatchCase Dialog False
    .MatchWholeWord Dialog False
    .MatchWildcards Dialog False
    .MatchSoundsLike Dialog False
    .MatchAllWordForms Dialog False
End With
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text Dialog _
        "word1  word2"
    .Replacement.Text Dialog "^p^c"
    .Forward Dialog True
    .Wrap Dialog wdFindAsk
    .Format Dialog False
    .MatchCase Dialog False
    .MatchWholeWord Dialog False
    .MatchWildcards Dialog False
    .MatchSoundsLike Dialog False
    .MatchAllWordForms Dialog False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
With Selection
    If .Find.Forward Dialog True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    If .Find.Forward Dialog True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    End If
    .Find.Execute
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you explain why you need the last line of a page to move to the next page.  There may be a simpler way to achieve what you want without VBA.

Comment: What's with 'Dialog' throughout your code?

Comment: I need to number each word of the document with a numeration under the words, sometimes at the end of the page I have just the words, without the numbers, so I need to move that line to the next page

Comment: I don't know what's Dialog for, I just record the macro, I didn't design it, but when running it, an error appears. Today I tried using wildcards for the replacement, but the term "Dialog" is still creating a problem.